# Validate If Request is coming in Sequence in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an application where user authenticate himself in first page and later on move on to other pages.

> Page 1  ( Authenticate & Save the credentials in variable)
>     |
>   Page 2 - Use the saved credentials & get the respective data from DB
>     |
>   Page 3 - Use the saved credentials & get the respective data from DB
>     |
>   Page n - Use the saved credentials & get the respective data from DB

So in the first page user will be Authenticate and he can move on to next page and the url will be like this:

```
http:\\ controller\Action1  -->   Page 1

http:\\ controller\Action2  -->   Page 2
```

Now, I want to make sure that user will not change the URL and jump to nth page from 1st page..  like..

```
http:\\ controller\Action1  -->   Page 1
```

to

```
http:\\ controller\Action17 -->   Page 17
```

As we are saving the credentials and he is authenticated user he can jump to any page he want to...I want to make sure that he follows the sequence ...In one single word..I dont want user to modify the URL and jump to any page he wanted...He should only modify to jump to NEXT PAGE not to any other page..

Comment: You will need to maintain a table of 'visited' pages (or a value for 'next page') for each user and check that in each method (and redirect if necessary)

Comment: Is AJAX an option? That way you can stay on the same page and interact with your server. There a number of jQuery Steps plugins that have a wizard look and feel. You'd have to implement some code to change the HTML which could be challenging.

Comment: You could check whether `Request.UrlReferrer` points to the previous action. But Referrers can be spoofed.

Comment: If you store the last visited page number somewhere (session?) you don't need a separate url for each page. Just a next page url which checks the last page number and displays the next one.

Comment: Store a dictionary<int, string> with the order an action name or url. Store the current step in Session and on each action call, check that value. If the  value is 2 and the user is on action 10, redirect him to 3. Then set the value to 3. Repeat for the next action call.

Comment: Hi..Without using sessions is their any other way.? I tried using childActionOnly..but no luck